# Is there some kind of session imitation for now web project in Java?

Tags: java, session, blogs

Basically the idea is that I need some sort of session/cookie imitation for Java. I have to develop some kind of a blogging program for a university project. It does not have to be for Web, I mean that I don't need servlet's and other Java EE stuff. The whole interface has to be in the console.

So here is the problem, I've developed a Menu class in which I add a MenuItem object for every menu option I want to be added, after I navigate my menu and I want to log into my account, I need something like a session, otherwise I cannot hide the "Login" and "Register" options, and can't decide whether to show the "Logout" option. Since the Menu class is instantiated only once, there is no way it could be updated on the go(or at least I think so, still learning Java).

If there is someone who can give me an advice or an idea, that would help me a lot.

**Here is the Menu class:**

```
package my.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import my.toolbox.InputHandler;

public class Menu extends MenuItem {

    protected SessionImitator SESSION = SessionImitator.getInstance();

    protected String title;

    private static final String OUT_OF_RANGE = "Please select an option within the range";

    private static final MenuItem SEPARATOR = new MenuItem("---------------------");
    private static final MenuItem BACK = new MenuItem("Go Back");
    private static final MenuItem EXIT = new MenuItem("Exit", new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    List<MenuItem> items;

    public Menu(String title, MenuItem ... items) {
        this(title, false, true, items);
    }

    public Menu(String title, boolean addBack, boolean addExit, MenuItem ... items) {
        super(title);
        setExecutable(this);

        init(addBack, addExit, items);
    }

    private void init(boolean addBack, boolean addExit, MenuItem ... items) {
        this.items = new ArrayList<MenuItem>(Arrays.asList());
        for (MenuItem item : items) {
            if (item.isSessionDependent()) {
                if (!item.getSessionAction() && SESSION.isSet()) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            this.items.add(item);
        }

        if (SESSION.isSet()) {
            System.out.println("THIS PART DOES NOT WORK SINCE THE OBJECT IT's NOT UPDATED AFTER THE SESSION IS SET!");
        }

        if (addBack) this.items.add(BACK);
        if (addExit) this.items.add(EXIT);
    }

    private void display() {
        int option = 0;

        System.out.println(SEPARATOR.getTitle());
        System.out.println(getTitle() + ":");
        System.out.println(SEPARATOR.getTitle());
        for (MenuItem item : items) {
            System.out.println((option++) + ": " + item.getTitle());
        }
        System.out.println(SEPARATOR.getTitle());
        System.out.println("select an option: ");
        System.out.flush();
    }

    private MenuItem prompt() {
        display();

        int option = InputHandler.readInt();

        if (option >= 0 && option < items.size()) {
            return items.get(option);
        }

        System.out.println(OUT_OF_RANGE);

        return null;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (MenuItem item = prompt(); item.isExecutable(); item = prompt()) {
                item.run();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

}
```

**The MenuItem class:**

```
package my.app;

public class MenuItem implements Runnable {

    private String title;
    private Runnable executable;
    private boolean sessionDependent;
    private boolean sessionAction;

    protected MenuItem(String title) {
        this(title, null, false, false);
    }

    protected MenuItem(String title, boolean sessionDependent, boolean sessionAction) {
        this(title, null, sessionDependent, sessionAction);
    }

    protected MenuItem(String title, Runnable executable) {
        this(title, executable, false, false);
    }

    public MenuItem(String title, Runnable executable, boolean sessionDependent, boolean sessionAction) {
        this.title = title;
        this.executable = executable;
        this.sessionDependent = sessionDependent;
        this.sessionAction = sessionAction;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            executable.run();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public boolean isExecutable() {
        return executable != null;
    }

    protected void setExecutable(Runnable executable) {
        this.executable = executable;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public boolean isSessionDependent() {
        return sessionDependent;
    }

    public boolean getSessionAction() {
        return sessionAction;
    }

}
```

**And the SessionImitator class:**

```
package my.app;

public class SessionImitator {

    private static SessionImitator instance = null;

    protected int userId;
    protected boolean locked = false;

    protected SessionImitator() {

    }

    public static SessionImitator getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SessionImitator();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String id) {
        if (!locked) {
            this.userId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        }
    }

    public boolean isSet() {
        return locked;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the program standalone, or does it interact with a server?

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's standalone since this is required by the task I got from the university. The task program is meant to be developed using the knowledge we gained form the lessons, and we did not got that far in Java learning.

Comment: @RaduDascalu, you are probably looking for something like "serialization". Gave more details in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing seems like you want to save a "state" of the program. But specifically of the state of the menu.

A simple implementation is to make your menu `serializable`, then save the serialized menu object to a file and reload it on login, if the file exists.

The above example would work for a user on a computer. If you wanted to persist across networks, etc. You might want to write the serialized object to a blob in a db table and then load it from there.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, going to save that as an option and do some research on Java serialization. It looks kinda messy at the first glance tho, please don't get me wrong, but are there more options, maybe something more delicate?

Answer (score 0):

If your program is standalone, what you need is a *container* to hold current state of the application. There are different ways to obtain that:

- a singleton: a dedicated class stores the state in its attributes and has a static member of its own class. That way you can get access to the state with code like `State state = State.getInstance()` - that is what your `SessionImitator` currently is.
- a simple object *injected* in all other classes that could need it. A way to build that is to create an instance of a class holding state and pass it (for example in constructor) of other classes:

  ```
  State state = new State();
  ...
  Menu menu = new Menu(state);
  ```
- a dependancy injection framework like Spring or Guice. It can help you to use the injection pattern but is really worthy when you have complex dependencies.